# Jmeter- Request sent to server with square bracket,

Tags: api, jmeter

I add username and password in URL, but Jmeter send request to server with square bracket.
username : ABC
password : 123

In sampler I have mentioned like this
https://ABC:123@api.google.com

but after execution it added brackets like this
https://[ABC:123@api.google.com]/path

due to this my API is failing, please help me out

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add anything but application under test IP or hostname into "Server Name or IP" input, if you want to include your credentials into URL use "Path" field instead:

[image]

However if you don't have an explicit requirement stating to send credentials in the URL I would rather recommend providing them using [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) as putting the whole URI into "Path" might cause other test elements malfunction, for example [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)

So suggested setup would be:

- HTTP Request sampler:

  [image]
- HTTP Authorization Manager

  [image]

More information: [How to Use HTTP Basic Authentication in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter/)